# How to detect if Respective API is called from IFrame in JQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, html5-canvas

I am stuck in a problem and I need the solution for it! 
I am using a IFrame in a web page, That Iframe has few content which I want to edit, but as it is a Cross Orgin, so I am getting blocked!

But I have noticed that when I perform any action on Iframe, in networks tab I can see some api getting called! So is there any way I can detect on every api call like which api is called from iframe? So I can match it with the one I need and perform action accordingly!?

Or if you can suggest something to me, how can I edit the content for cross origin?

Comment: There is no way to do it inside a cross domain iframe using code in parent page.

Comment: There are good reasons for this not being allowed and is exactly what cross-origin was meant for - to prevent people snooping, intercepting or otherwise meddling with pages that aren't theirs.

Comment: But since you never said you don't own all these domains/are in control of these pages' content, you might be interested in the [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) API.

Comment: Basically I need to edit the message once the puzzle is solved! http://palgharbazaar.com/jpuzzle/honda_puzzle/ Or if we can detect, if user has completed the puzzle, and then we can show our own custom message... Please help! Let me the solution or right path!